# CakePHP and HABTM Tag Filtering

Tags: cakephp, filtering, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am wrestling around a bit with CakePHP HABTM relationships, and I've gotten stuck trying to do a seemingly simple task.  I have many Camps and many NewsItems.  Each NewsItem could be relevant to any of the camps, so when a user creates a NewsItem, they check which Camps the item is for.  That's the idea.

So...

I would like to incorporate some camp filtering into my NewsItems views.  In other words, I would like to see all NewsItems relevant to Camp "A" and Camp "B".

Adding conditions to the "find" and "paginate" functions work like a charm.

However...

If a NewsItem belongs to multiple Camps, it appears multiple times in the list.  So when I tell find to give me all NewsItems that belong to Camp "A" and Camp "B", a NewsItem that belongs to Camp "A" and Camp "B" will appear twice.

The debug query looks like this:

> SELECT `NewsItem`.`id`, `NewsItem`.`user_id`, `NewsItem`.`heading`, `NewsItem`.`body`, `NewsItem`.`modified`, `User`.`first_name` FROM `news_items` AS `NewsItem` LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` ON (`NewsItem`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `camps_news_items` AS `CampsNewsItem` ON (`CampsNewsItem`.`news_item_id` = `NewsItem`.`id`) WHERE `CampsNewsItem`.`camp_id` IN (1, 5) ORDER BY `NewsItem`.`modified` desc LIMIT 10
>
> SELECT `Camp`.`id`, `Camp`.`name`, `Camp`.`created`, `Camp`.`modified`, `CampsNewsItem`.`camp_id`, `CampsNewsItem`.`news_item_id` FROM `camps` AS `Camp` JOIN `camps_news_items` AS `CampsNewsItem` ON (`CampsNewsItem`.`news_item_id` IN (6, 6, 7, 8) AND `CampsNewsItem`.`camp_id` = `Camp`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1

The php code looks like this:

```
$camp_ids = array(1, 3, 6, 10);
$conditions = array('CampsNewsItem.camp_id' => $camp_ids);
    
$params['conditions'] = $conditions;
$this->NewsItem->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('CampsNewsItem')));
$news_items = $this->NewsItem->find('all', $params);
```

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$params['group'] = array('NewsItem.id');
```

Comment: Any idea how to get that to work properly with the paginate helper?